# AWS Windows Server Hosting: Ports other than 80 not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting

I am not able to access ports other than port 80 in my `AWS hosting`.

I hosted my App in http://18.222.65.31. This port is working as expected, but I hosted another app in http://18.222.65.31:81/api/values, which is not working outside the hosted instance of AWS.

What I tried so far:

> 1. I added firewall Inbound Rule for port 81.
> 2. Added Custom TCP rule for the security group of the instance from AWS Console.

Is there something I am missing ?

**UPDATE:**

**1. Instance Detail:**

[image]

**2. Security Group detail:**

[image]

**3. VM Firewall Advanced Settings(Inbound):**

[image]

Comment: Does it work locally localhost:81 on windows?

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-network-security.html) to know how to set Security Groups for Windows Instances.

Comment: When you say "AWS hosting", are you referring to an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, what is the configuration of the Security Group that is associated with this Amazon EC2 instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I added http port 80 , TCP port 81 and even tried TCP all inbound rule and selected "everywhere" option. Same thing I did on Windows Firewall of the instance. I did the same thing for 8080 port 3-4 month back, which is working fine,any new assignment of port isn't working now.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated the question(Added some screenshots)

Comment: @BrandoZhang I added some screenshots with the question.

Comment: @JamesDean yes. It does. I updated the question(Added some screenshots)

Comment: @BimalDas did you resolve this?

Comment: @numX sorry I solved but I forgot :(

Comment: @BimalDas - Any direction you can point me on solving this would be more than amazing. I have almost exactly the same issue (just picked different port numbers)